# Security warning for EXE files in specific path

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, security-warning

All .exe files in `F:\Program\Install` on my PC are showing Security Warning when clicked:
[image]

it is shown for apps that don't have valid signature, but apps like CPU-Z (which have digital signature) will show security warning too, but a little different:
[image]

The problam is that both verified and non verified files will not load after clicking `Run`, and the error says the program can't access Temp folder. Running exes as administrator will bypass security warning and show the second error (can't access temp...).

I installed a fresh windows, changed the default `%Temp%` path to `c:\` , checked temp permissions, but it didn't work. Now I'm absolutely sure that the problem is not from Temp but F: drive permissions! If i move any of the .exe files in `F:\Program\Install` (or its sub-directories) to upper roots or another drives, it will execute without any errors!

Comment: Could you clarify - is f:\program\install a local or a network location?

Comment: it's a local hard disk. i'm not connected to any network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let deal with the CPU ID case first...

This prompt shows up when a file is downloaded from other sources. Right click on the file, click the box `Unblock` and you will not see that popup again. If you didn't, everything extracted from this zip will have this tag, and this cannot be done with multiple files you select.

[image: Unblock button]

Now please screenshot the Security tab of your F:. You may need to reset the permissions if the F: partition was created by another Windows computer/Previous Windows.

By default, the permission would be `Authenticated Users`, `SYSTEM`, `Administrators (<PC NAME>\Administrators` and `Users <PC NAME>\Users`

**UPDATE**

Browse to `F:\Program`, right click `Install`, Properties. In Security tab, click the Advanced button. Then click button `Change Permissions...`. Tick both check boxes: "Include inheritable..." and "Replace all child object permissions...", then click OK. it should then rewrite security settings for folders and files within `Install`.

Comment: thanks for answering.  
There is no `Unblock` button for CPU-Z.exe or any other EXE file in that directory! here's the screenshot: http://www.img.ir/xKnc.jpg   
And here's Security tab of F root: http://www.img.ir/wKnc.jpg   
Something strange: i just connected my laptop (with Win8) to this PC (Win7) and shared `F:\Install\Program` folder on the laptop.then i executed CPU-Z.exe via network, in laptop, and it was executed without any errors even Security Warning!! i'm really surprised now that how can this happen :O

Comment: thanks but ticking does two didnt made any difference. is it possible if i move all files in F: to another drive , format F and then restoring files to F ?

Comment: Don't move them, copy them. Move will copy permission too. When done, format the F: then copy to it. Then delete the temp copy.

Comment: SOLVED ! i copied F: content to another drive, formated F: , and restored its content. now all programs in `F:` and `F:\Program\Install` working as well as it was before.i'm just wondering what was the exact problem and where are File Permissions stored! anyway, Thanks Patrick for everything :)